# How to show a bubble hint?

Tags: codenameone

I noticed that the `InteractionDialog` class should be useable as a bubble help and tried this:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
    Command commandDummy = new Command("Dummy");
    hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(commandDummy);
    CN.callSerially(() -> {
        InteractionDialog interactionDialog = new InteractionDialog("hint");
        interactionDialog.add(new Label("this is supposed to be a hint"));
        interactionDialog.showPopupDialog(hi.getToolbar().findCommandComponent(commandDummy));
    });
    hi.show();
```

But it is not really satisfying because the bubble doesn't really point to the component. Also the bubble is not always shown.

Is `InteractionDialog` the right tool to show a bubble help? Can it be configured that it works with all skins? And why is does the bubbles pointer not really point where it should point to - the "Dummy" component?

Here are the screen shots:

[image: Simulator Desktop Skin]

[image: Simulator iPhone 5c Skin]

[image: Simulator Nexus 5X Skin]

Answer (score 0):

`InteractionDialog` is fine, it's limited to the area of the `ContentPane` though. The main problem is the arrow border as explained in this issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2689

Currently iOS has a hardcoded limited arrow border implementation that doesn't let us position the arrow anywhere we want. Also it's a feature of the iOS theme only. You can add styling to `PopupDialog` for your own theme and get a similar result for other themes too.